# configure button on canvas in python

Tags: python, tkinter, button, canvas, configure

I'm working on GUI project and I'm trying to configure a button color and text but it gives me an error..
here is a sample of my code:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
#root
root = Tk()
root.geometry('640x520')

#Canvas 
myCanvas = Canvas(root, width=350, height=300, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
myCanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
def qu1():
    global myCanvas
    myCanvas.itemconfig(Q1,bg='green',text= 'Done')
Q1 = Button(root, width=15, height=10, bg='#F3C4B7',fg='white', text='1', command=qu1)
myCanvas.create_window(10,10, anchor='nw', window=Q1)
root.mainloop()
```

it gives me this error:

```
line 12, in qu1
    myCanvas.itemconfig(Q1,bg='green',text= 'Done')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression
```

Comment: `itemconfig` applies to `Canvas` objects, Q1 is not! The `myCanvas` declaration returns the item you need to use. So apply `item = myCanvas(...` then use it instead of Q1.

Comment: First you need to use the item ID returned by `.create_window(...)` in `.itemconfig()`.  Second you cannot use `.itemconfig()` to change the `bg` and `text` options of a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already stated:

> itemconfig applies to Canvas objects

You can do:

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.geometry('640x520')
myCanvas = Canvas(root, width=350, height=300, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
myCanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
buttonBG = myCanvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 30, fill="grey40", outline="grey60")
buttonTXT = myCanvas.create_text(50, 15, text="click")
def qu1(event):
    myCanvas.itemconfig(buttonBG, fill='red')
    myCanvas.itemconfig(buttonTXT, fill='white')
myCanvas.tag_bind(buttonBG, "<Button-1>", qu1)
myCanvas.tag_bind(buttonTXT, "<Button-1>", qu1)
root.mainloop()
```

Or change the button itself:

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.geometry('640x520')
myCanvas = Canvas(root, width=350, height=300, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
myCanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
def qu1():
    Q1.configure(bg="#234")
Q1 = Button(root, width=15, height=10, bg='#F3C4B7',fg='white', text='1', command=qu1)
myCanvas.create_window(10,10, anchor='nw', window=Q1)
root.mainloop()
```